# Application crashes in dynamic module

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

So i'm trying to implement dynamic module. I just have one fragment in the dynamic module i.e  upon clicking on that fragment, it downloads the module and installs and then it is showed to the user. So far the application is downloading and installing the module. But it crashes upon loading the module. It throws following error

```
29-05-2022 20:05:02 : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7d020000

--------- Stack trace ---------

android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2400)
android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530)
com.healtharx.ondemand.OnDemandFragment.onCreateView(OnDemandFragment.kt:16)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
```

If i run the application from android studio where it obviously downloads and installs all modules, the application runs fine. But when i upload the application to playstore for internal testing, it downloads and installs the module and throws the above error. What am i missing? Also if anyone can share good online resource which can help me implement dynamic module easily it would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not clear if you are following the codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery#6